# Merge similar rows and sum their values?

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
URL           | Art | Design 
example1.com     1             
example1.com     1             
example1.com     1             
example1.com            1         
example2.com            1
example2.com            1
```

I want to merge columns with same URL and sum the values of Art and Design in the process, to get something like:

```
URL           | Art | Design
example1.com     3      1
example2.com            2
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use GROUP BY and [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum):

```
SELECT URL, SUM(Art) as Art, SUM(Design) AS Design
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY URL
```

Comment: Your answer seems just merges the query instead of operating the real table storage, how to write the group by result back to table?

Comment: You can use the "INSERT ... SELECT" syntax to write the results of a query to a table: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 1):

```
select URL,sum(art),sum(design) From MYTABLE group by URl
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select url,SUM(art),SUM(design) from  tab1 group by url
```

Where tab1 is your table name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT URL, COUNT(Art), COUNT(Design)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything till now?

It is as simple as:

```
select url, SUM(art) as Art, SUM(design) as Design from [MyTable] group by url
```